# How do I return a correct category from a list of categories. When it's not an exact match of words?

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, match

I have a list of categories, here is the list, and it is contained in a drop down. This is column I

```
Product Type
Nails
Screws
Bolts
Nuts
Anchors
Staples
Washers
Sets
Powder Loads
Rivets
Rivet Tool
Hammer Tacker
Staple Gun
Soldering Iron
Insert Tool
Caps
```

I want to go through this list of item types and to align them/categorize them to the correct categories. Here is the list. this is in Column K

```
Item Type: Fender Washer
Item Type: Fender Washer
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Sleeve Anchor
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Deck Screw
Item Type: Deck Screw
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Sleeve Anchor
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Screw Anchor
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Sleeve Anchor
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Masonry Screw
Item Type: Plow Bolt
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Screw Anchor
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Plow Bolt
Item Type: Sleeve Anchor
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Wall Anchor
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Sleeve Anchor
Item Type: Masonry Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Wall Anchor
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Deck Screw
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Plow Bolt
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Screw Anchor
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Sleeve Anchor
Item Type: Masonry Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Socket Cap Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Sleeve Anchor
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Masonry Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Tap Bolt
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Wall Anchor
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Fender Washer
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Screw Anchor
Item Type: Fender Washer
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Sleeve Anchor
Item Type: Screw Anchor
Item Type: Masonry Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Tap Bolt
Item Type: Screw Anchor
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Tap Bolt
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Hex Nut
Item Type: Masonry Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Tap Bolt
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Screw Anchor
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Socket Cap Screw
Item Type: Socket Cap Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Tap Bolt
Item Type: Tap Bolt
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Tap Bolt
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Socket Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Tap Bolt
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Masonry Screw
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Screw Anchor
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Deck Screw
Item Type: Deck Screw
Item Type: Deck Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Socket Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Fender Washer
Item Type: Lock Nut
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Lock Nut
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Tap Bolt
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Lock Nut
Item Type: Self-Drilling Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Tap Bolt
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Tap Bolt
Item Type: Hex Lag Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Lock Nut
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Lock Nut
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Self-Drilling Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Tap Bolt
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Lock Nut
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Cap Screw
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Carriage Bolt
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
Item Type: Sheet Metal Screw
```

I have tried various types of index and match, left(cell,3), and it still can't find the right characters and return the correct category. When it did return a category for some reason it returned Nails for Fender Washer item types.

Comment: Please fix your post using correct markdown syntax. It's unreadable

Comment: Please provide a _minimal_ example of your data and expected result

Comment: Is a cap screw a cap or a screw?  There's a whole lot you're not telling us.

Comment: @JvdV done...though it would be nice to see what the expected output would be

Comment: Please provide the expected output for your input sample (or a subset of the input data), so we can understand better the rules to apply? Thanks

Comment: I will do this correctly today, and reformat the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better to provide a minimal subset of your data, both to save space and to clarify exactly what your asking whereas you appear to have quoted your entire Product Type list.

Product Type seems to be specified within Item Type although Product Type seems to be frequently (but inconsistently) pluralised which makes a look-up more complicated. That aside, soemthing like this should work:

```
    =LET(
        lstWrd, TEXTAFTER( K2, " ", -1),
        ctgs, I$1:I$23,
        isPlrl, LOWER( RIGHT( TRIM( ctgs), 1)) = "s",
        ctg, IF( isPlrl, LEFT( ctgs, LEN( ctgs) - 1), ctgs)),
        XLOOKUP( lstWrd, ctg, ctg)
    )
```

This will look up the 2nd item in your Item Type list (K2 - ignoring headers) and return the category from your Product Type list in column I. Copy this formula down your list (or you could turn this into an array formula).

It uses the new(ish) Ecel text functions (TEXTAFTER) within a LET function to sequentially:

- get the last word from the Item Type list
- take the Product Type List (labelled ctgs)
- check if each item in that list is plural [has a final s]
- if it has remove the last letter and label that list of singulars ctg
- lookup the last word of Item Type in the singularised list of Product Type

Comment: Whilst I stand by the above, and hopefully it contains techniques you'll find useful, the problem as stated is unusual and likely to lead to errors: you can't normally rely on the product type essentially being a substring of the item type. This could change at any time when someone (else) added a new Item Type that didn't conform to this convention. More usually (and robustly), You would have an array elsewehere in your Excel sheet, which sould assign a Product Type to each Item Type. You would then look up a Product Type for each item.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will also clean my question up as well.